# SQL join with condition of last item of the right table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Sorry if the title is not really understandable, I've trouble even expressing it!

To simplify, I have two tables in a SQL Server 2012 database: one with requests  and one with actions related to these requests (it's from a service manager software)

```
Table REQUESTS            Table ACTIONS
+------+-------+---+      +---------+------+--------+
|Req_ID|RFC_Num|...|      |Action_ID|Req_ID|Group_ID|
+------+-------+---+      +---------+------+--------+
| 1    | I01   |...|      |  a      | 1    | 10     |
| 2    | I02   |...|      |  b      | 1    | 20     |
| 3    | I03   |...|      |  c      | 1    | 38     |
| 4    | I04   |...|      |  d      | 1    | 38     |
+------+-------+---+      |  e      | 2    | 10     |
                          |  f      | 2    | 38     |
                          |  g      | 2    | 20     |
                          |  h      | 3    | 38     |
                          |  i      | 4    | 10     |
                          +---------+------+--------+
```

I want to be able to select all requests where the last action for that request has group_id = 38, so it should return requests with req_id is 1 and 3, but not req2 as the last action is made by another group than 38 nor req4 as group 38 is not involved.

I've tried things like

```
select *
from REQUEST r
inner join ACTION a 
    on (
        (r.REQUEST_ID = a.REQUEST_ID) 
        and (select group_id 
            from ACTION a2 
            where a2.action_id = a.action_id
            ).GROUP_ID = 38
        )
```

but I can't figure out how to put the "max(action_id)" (or select top 1 with an order by desc) and I don't really understand how to use things like having.

I've also tried requests like this one:

```
select *
from REQUEST r
inner join ACTION a 
    on (
        (r.REQUEST_ID = a.REQUEST_ID) 
        and (select top 1 a2.action_id, a2.group_id 
            from ACTION a2 
            where a2.action_id = a.action_id
            group by a2.ACTION_ID
            order by a2.action_id desc
            ).GROUP_ID = 38
        )
```

But I get these two errors:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> Column ACTION.GROUP_ID is not valid in the selection list because it's not contained in an aggregation function or in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
> Only one expression can be specified in the selection list when the subquery is not introduced by EXISTS.

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks longer than it needs to be. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM requests r
WHERE (
    SELECT TOP 1 Group_ID
    FROM actions
    WHERE Req_ID = r.Req_ID
    ORDER BY Action_ID DESC
) = 38
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3c2b0/1/0)

Comment: Thanks, so simple but it did it!

Answer (score 0):

Your join column is wrong, you are using:

```
(r.REQUEST_ID = a.ACTION_ID)
```

but should be:

```
(r.REQUEST_ID = a.REQUEST_ID)
```

Comment: Yes you're right, I'll edit my first message, but even with this I can't figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You could join the tables, only keeping records `WHERE Group_ID = 38` and no other action for this request exists with a greater `Action_ID`.

```
SELECT r.*
       FROM REQUESTS r
            INNER JOIN ACTIONS a
                       ON a.Req_ID = r.Req_ID
       WHERE a.Group_ID = 38
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM ACTIONS ai
                                    WHERE ai.Req_ID = a.Req_ID
                                          AND ai.Action_ID > a.Action_ID);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1925f/11)

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use `apply`:

```
select r.*, a.*
from request r cross apply
     (select top 1 a.*
      from action a
      where a.request_id = a.request_id
      order by a.action_id desc
     )
where a.group_id = 38;
```

This assumes that "last action" is based on the `action_id` column.  Whatever the definition is is what the `order by` uses.